# Sequencing ASP.NET custom validators and difference between Validator's Text and ErrorMessage properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, validation, customvalidator

I have a `TextBox` with two validators. The first validator checks if the `TextBox` is empty or not. The second validator checks that the value of `TextBox` contains spaces or not. But when I run the project and try to validate without any text in `TextBox`, it shows both validators' error messages. What I want is that it should not execute second validator until the first validator is validated successfully.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ErrorMessage="Please enter some value." Font-Names="Segoe UI" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:CustomValidator>
<br />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ErrorMessage="Spaces are not allowed." Font-Names="Segoe UI" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator2_ServerValidate" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:CustomValidator>
<br />
```

So my questions are:

How can I sequence the validations so that one validation should be called after other is validated successfully?

Another question that I want to ask is that what is the difference between Validator's Text and ErrorMessage properties?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `RequiredFieldValidator` for empty text, and then a `CustomValidator` to check out the string composition.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
 ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"
 ControlToValidate="TextBox3"  
 runat="server"     
 ErrorMessage="Please enter some value.">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<br />
<asp:CustomValidator 
 ID="CustomValidator2" 
 runat="server" 
 ControlToValidate="TextBox3" 
 ErrorMessage="Spaces are not allowed." 
 Font-Names="Segoe UI" 
 OnServerValidate="CustomValidator2_ServerValidate" SetFocusOnError="True">
</asp:CustomValidator>
<br />
```

The [ErrorMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.aspx) From MSDN:

> Gets or sets the text for the error message displayed in a
>   ValidationSummary control when validation fails.

The [Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.aspx) From MSDN:

> Gets or sets the text displayed in the validation control when
>   validation fails. (Overrides Label.Text.)

EDIT:

Given that you are doing multiple validations, you should use a Single `CustomValidator` for this. In the server side, you should check both, Empty and then String composition, something like this:

```
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Value))
  {
    args.IsValid = false;
    ((CustomValidator)source).Text = "Please enter some value.";
  }
  else if (/*Check if has empty space*/)
  {
    args.IsValid = false;
    ((CustomValidator)source).Text = "Spaces are not allowed.";
  }
  else
  {
    args.IsValid = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: I already tried using `RequiredFieldValidator`, but the effect is same. And about the difference between ErrorMessage and Text, I think setting the value of anyone of them will show the error message. So what's the actual difference? Or is there any difference?

Comment: I just wrote the difference from MSDN. And, If you tried, theres something else wrong in the Server method, thats returning isValid = false every time, you should take a look.

Comment: My validators are working fine. The problem is they are working simultaneously. I mean if first validation fails the other validator should not be executed.

Comment: Edited my answear, checkout!

Answer (score 2):

Answer to question: `How can I sequence the validations so that one validation should be called after other is validated successfully ?`

The validators that you add in a .aspx page, they are added to `Page.Validators` collection in the same order they are created. The validation runs in the order they are present in the Page.Validators collection.Thus the  first validator in the aspx file is first in Page.Validators. If you want to rearrange the order, then the correct way is to arrange your validators in the page in the same order you want them to fire.

**NOTE:** the validators will fire one by one. in case you don't want the very next validators to fire you may use Javascript to disable the next ones. call a ClientValidation function in first validator

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox3"
     ClientValidationFunction="disableNextVal" ....
```

// Sample JavaScript code

```
function disableNextVal()
{
 // firstly check here for first condition, if First condition fails,
 // disable the next validator as below.
  var nextCustomVal = document.getElementById('nextCustomValidatorClientID');
  ValidatorEnable(myVal, false); 
// or use this one:
  myVal.enabled = false;
}
```

//Also seeing your requirement, one more possibility seems is of MaskValidator. [Check here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx).

```
2nd question:
```

Difference between `Text` & `ErrorMessage` property:

`Text` : The message displayed  when validation fails. This usually  appears next to your control say a TextBox.This is not associated with a `ValidationSummary` control.

`ErrorMessage` : The text displayed  in the `ValidationSummary` control when validation fails. In case you have not set the `Text` property above, This `ErrorMessage` value will be displayed in the validation control.

Comment: Actually I want to cancel the other validation if the first one fails. The problem is both of them are executing simultaneously.

Comment: Edited my answer for the same. See the section: NOTE

Answer (score 1):

Although a slightly different tack, ValidationSummary may be helpful for you.